# Notepad++ Bad Allocation - where do I find the restore files?

Tags: notepad++

My Notepad++ just closed because of "Bad Allocation". I didn't know it would close before it was too late. Eager to work on, I just clicked away an error message that read sth like "All I could save, I saved to <filepath>/<filename>, but there is some data loss". Where would I find the file path with all the restored data?

Comment: This is entirely depends on your configuration.  The error message should have indicated where the recovered file should be located it.  Its possible it actually failed to generate the file, if that happen, then there isn't actually restored data.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the error message has indicated, but I clicked away. Is there any way, except trying to get another "Bad Allocation" error, to posthumously find out where such a file is normally stored?

Comment: That is controlled by a program variable which can be set in the options menu. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712139/notepad-how-to-recover-a-deleted-file)